# What is the difference between <int:pk> and <pk>?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Say that we are implementing a simple blog with django and that the blog posts are accessible with URLs like `/posts/1/`, `/posts/2/` etc.

When we define the path variables in the urlpatterns array, what is the main difference between using
`path('post/<int:pk>/', ..., ...)` and `path('post/<pk>/', ..., ...)`?

Is it just good practice? Are there actual benefits?

Comment: Do you want to accept `pk` values that aren't integers?

Comment: No, not necessarily. Let's assume that all our ```pk``` values are integers.

Comment: If you use `<int:pk>`, then your view is guaranteed to receive an actual integer value.  Otherwise you have to worry about parsing the integer yourself, and handle any errors that arise when you're passed a non-integer string value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it just good practice? Are there actual benefits?

**Yes**. It makes the path more specific, and allows to write other paths that do not have overlapping patterns.

The `int:` part is a [*path converter* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters). If you do not specify a path converter the `str` path converter will be used.

It specifies the regex that will be used. For example the [**`IntConverter`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/urls/converters.py#L5-L12) has as regex:

> ```
> class IntConverter:
>     regex = '[0-9]+'
>
>     def to_python(self, value):
>         return int(value)
>
>     def to_url(self, value):
>         return str(value)
> ```

whereas the [`StringConverter` [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/urls/converters.py#L15-L22) uses:

> ```
> class StringConverter:
>     regex = '[^/]+'
>
>     def to_python(self, value):
>         return value
>
>     def to_url(self, value):
>         return value
> ```

These are thus regexes that replace the `<int:pk>` or `<str:pk>` in a path. If you thus simply write `<pk>`, then it will also fire for `post/foobar`. You do not per se want this. For example if you later have another path:

```
    path('post/<int:pk>/', some_view),
    path('post/new/', other_view),
```

If you would write `<pk>` then the `post/new` path would also fire the `some_view` view, and not the `other_view`, since the `str:` path converter also matches with `new`.